# Are mysql server 5.6 and mysql (client) 5.5 full compatible?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

I am bit novice in some aspects here and no related information found...

I have an AWS instance with mysql client installed at 5.5 version. And also an RDS db instance with mysql 5.6 (in order to use t2.micro). I don't think so but, could this in your opinion/experience produce some kind of trouble when requesting queries (via PHP, specifically Symfony2) between them?

I hope it is no; but if yes, is strictly necessary then to upgrade my mysql client in the instance or there is any other way to use t2.micro with mysql server at 5.5?

Any guidance or related experience would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think for querying and taking db connection it's ok,but for few administration works require same client version that server has.just an example of gtid option in mysqldump i.e --set-gtid-purged=OFF introduce in 5.6, if you  use this option with 5.5 client you will get error as use of invalid option even though its valid variable option in 5.6 server.may be there are more,better to use same client version that server has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Upgrading from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html):

> Note particularly any changes that are marked Known issue or
>   Incompatible change.

That said, your client app should be able to use 5.6 safely, and you got it right, that is required to use db.t2.micro instances.